# Polymorphism with C++11 futures

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, std

Say I have two futures, `future<int> a` and `future<char> b`. Is there any way to put both of these (or pointers to them) into any of the standard containers (`std::{list,vector,...}`?

The problem I intend to solve with this:

Setup: I have a thread pool library that allows the user to submit tasks in the form of arbitrary functions w/ arguments as tasks. The pool executes the function w/ args in a worker thread and the result is communicated to the user by a `future<func::result_type>`, where `func` is an `std::function<?>`. (? Being a wildcard, b/c it words with any function.) These futures are also the only external way to wait on a task to complete. If one only wants to wait until they execute, one must call `future::get()` and ignore the result.

Problem: I want to provide a way to wait on all the tasks currently in the queue. To do this, I need to keep a list of all the futures so I can call `get` on them.

The library I'm talking about, in case you really need context (280 loc): https://github.com/Tyler-Hardin/thread_pool

Comment: Can you give an example of a problem you will solve with this? If you had it, how would it be used?

Comment: This question is really two different questions.

Comment: @Johan, it's a somewhat deep problem, but I can post it.

Comment: I have an answer ready, but I'm at work and want to check it at lunch properly before posting it.

Comment: Mostly because C++ really isn't to be supposed to be used like Java.

Comment: I believe the well-known reason is that polymorphism has a cost, and it's easier to add polymorphism to a design that uses concrete types than to remove it from one that uses interfaces.

Comment: @MorphingDragon, true. Secondary question removed.

Comment: @JohanLundberg, example added.

Comment: @Tyler mousing over the arrows displays why pepole typically downvote things.

Comment: @MorphingDragon, I disagree that the question fits that description, at least in its current form, with a legitimate motivating use case for the answer. But I'm obviously biased.

Comment: you can also use (lambda) function wrappers with void return type to ignore the return values.

Comment: Ignoring the ret vals isn't the issue. It's keeping a reference to them so I have an object to call get on. Unless I'm misunderstanding. If you have an alternative method, post an answer. I'd like to see it. (That might sound negative. Not intended.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand why you would need this, but you can use a standard technique - template wrappers with common base class:

```
class FutureHolderBase {
public:
    virtual ~FutureHolderBase() = default;
};

template<typename T>
class FutureHolder : public FutureHolderBase {
private:
    std::future<T> m_future;
};

int main() {
    // unfortunately can't use list-initialization here because it supports only copyable types
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<FutureHolderBase>> v;
    v.push_back(std::make_unique<FutureHolder<int>>());
    v.push_back(std::make_unique<FutureHolder<float>>());
}
```